# How to set percentage value below Label in Pie chart

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to place Percentage value(0.92) below, Label(EUR) in Pie chart. As shown below picture example.

[image]

I using MPAndroidChart, in which its showing as below
[image]

I tried to set using value below lable using library but not found it.

Please help on it.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a library to make the pie chart? If so what library?

Comment: Use MP Chart library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: yes, I use MPAndroidChart only, in Value upside and Lable below it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setUsePercentValues Parameter and set value true.

```
mPieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
```

Comment: and for the sign you have to user 
 `pieData.setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter())`

Answer (score 0):

set this:

```
setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter())
```

to PieData